# Get string from some textfield in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with 5 cells each cell has its own identifier I am trying to get and `print` strings from each UITextFields, I have some labels as well. Here is my code :

```
 let index: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:0 ,  inSection: 0)
            let cell: CustomCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! CustomCell
            print(cell.title.text!)
```

it works fine until I set row value dynamically, for example if textfield from cell 0 is selected print `cell.title.text` if textfield string is from cell 1 print its value. so I add this line of code :

```
   let IndexPath:NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        switch IndexPath.row {
        case 0:
            row = 0

        case 1:
            row = 1

        default:
            break
        }


            let index: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row /***CHANGED VALUE***/ ,  inSection: 0)
            let cell: CustomCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! CustomCell
            print(cell.title.text!)
```

app crashes at this line :

```
let IndexPath:NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

due to `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Any help would be great !

Comment: As always, do not get data from the view (the cell), get it from the model (the data source array)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexPathForSelectedRow` can return a `nil`when you did not select any row. So you have to check if it exists before any unwrappring operation.

```
if let IndexPath:NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    //do your work
}
```